# Slider Images Loop not Working

Tags: jquery, html, revolution-slider

Can you please help me on how to make the images from the slider, images 1.jpg and 2.jpg load once and 2a,2b,3.jpg will continue loading. So the loop should look like 1,2,2a,2b,3.jpg when it loops again it's 2a,2b,3.jpg. Hope you help me thanks in advance

Here is the code.

```
<section id="slider" class="slider-parallax revslider-wrap clearfix">
            <div class="slider-parallax-inner">

                <div class="tp-banner-container rev_slider_wrapper fullscreen-container">
                    <div class="tp-banner" >
                        <ul>    <!-- SLIDE  -->

                            <li data-transition="fade" data-slotamount="1" data-masterspeed="1000" data-thumb="images/slider/rev/main/1.jpg"  data-saveperformance="off"  data-title="" >
                                <img src="images/slider/rev/main/1.jpg"  alt=""  data-bgposition="center center" data-bgfit="cover" data-bgrepeat="no-repeat" data-bgparallax="10" class="rev-slidebg" data-no-retina>

                                    <!-- LAYER NR. 1 -->
                                    <div class="tp-fade fadeout fullscreenvideo rs-background-video-layer"
                                        data-forcerewind="on"
                                        data-volume="mute"
                                        data-videowidth="100%"
                                        data-videoheight="100%"
                                        data-videomp4="images/upcnew.mp4"
                                        data-videopreload="preload"
                                        data-videoloop="none"
                                        data-forceCover="1"
                                        data-aspectratio="16:9"
                                        data-autoplay="true"
                                        data-autoplayonlyfirsttime="false"
                                        data-nextslideatend="true"
                                        >
                                    </div>

                            </li>

                            <li class="tp-fade fadeout" data-transition="slideup" data-slotamount="1" data-masterspeed="1500" data-thumb="images/slider/rev/main/2.jpg" data-delay="3000" data-saveperformance="off" data-title="">

                                <img src="images/slider/rev/main/2.jpg"  alt="kenburns6"  data-bgposition="right center" data-kenburns="on" data-duration="3000" data-delay="3000" data-ease="Linear.easeNone" >

                            </li>

                            <li class="tp-fade fadeout" data-transition="slideup" data-slotamount="1" data-masterspeed="1500" data-thumb="images/slider/rev/main/2a.jpg" data-delay="3000" data-saveperformance="off" data-title="">

                                <img src="images/slider/rev/main/2a.jpg"  alt="kenburns6"  data-bgposition="right center" data-kenburns="on" data-duration="3000" data-delay="3000" data-ease="Linear.easeNone" >

                            </li>

                            <li class="tp-fade fadeout" data-transition="slideup" data-slotamount="1" data-masterspeed="1500" data-thumb="images/slider/rev/main/2b.jpg" data-delay="3000" data-saveperformance="off" data-title="">

                                <img src="images/slider/rev/main/2b.jpg"  alt="kenburns6"  data-bgposition="right center" data-kenburns="on" data-duration="3000" data-delay="3000" data-ease="Linear.easeNone" >

                            </li>

                            <li class="tp-fade fadeout" data-transition="slideup" data-slotamount="1" data-masterspeed="1500" data-thumb="images/slider/rev/main/3.jpg" data-delay="5000"  data-saveperformance="off"  data-title="">

                                <img src="images/slider/rev/main/3.jpg"  alt="kenburns6"  data-bgposition="left top" data-kenburns="on" data-duration="5000" ata-delay="5000" data-ease="Linear.easeNone" >

                                <!-- scroll down -->    
                                <a href="#" data-scrollto="#section-about" class="one-page-arrow dark">
                                    <i class="icon-angle-down infinite animated fadeInDown"></i>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>

                    </div>


                </div>

            </div>


        </section>
```

JQUERY

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var tpj=jQuery;
    tpj.noConflict();

    tpj(document).ready(function() {

        var apiRevoSlider = tpj('.tp-banner').show().revolution(
        {
            sliderType:"standard",
            jsFileLocation:"include/rs-plugin/js/",
            sliderLayout:"fullscreen",
            dottedOverlay:"none",
            delay:9000,
            responsiveLevels:[1200,992,768,480,320],
            startwidth:1140,
            startheight:600,
            hideThumbs:200,

            thumbWidth:100,
            thumbHeight:50,
            thumbAmount:3,

            navigation: {
                keyboardNavigation:"off",
                keyboard_direction: "horizontal",
                mouseScrollNavigation:"off",
                onHoverStop:"off",
                touch:{
                    touchenabled:"on",
                    swipe_threshold: 75,
                    swipe_min_touches: 1,
                    swipe_direction: "horizontal",
                    drag_block_vertical: false
                },
                arrows: {
                   /* style: "hermes",
                    enable: true,*/
                    hide_onmobile: false,
                   /* hide_onleave: false,*/
                   /* tmp: '<div class="tp-arr-allwrapper"> <div class="tp-arr-imgholder"></div>    <div class="tp-arr-titleholder">{{title}}</div> </div>',*/
                    left: {
                       /* h_align: "left",
                        v_align: "center",
                        h_offset: 10,
                        v_offset: 0*/
                    },
                    right: {
                       /* h_align: "right",
                        v_align: "center",
                        h_offset: 10,
                        v_offset: 0*/
                    }
                }
            },

            touchenabled:"on",
            onHoverStop:"on",

            swipe_velocity: 0.7,
            swipe_min_touches: 1,
            swipe_max_touches: 1,
            drag_block_vertical: false,


            parallax:"mouse",
            parallaxBgFreeze:"on",
            parallaxLevels:[8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1],
            parallaxDisableOnMobile:"on",

            keyboardNavigation:"on",

            shadow:0,
            fullWidth:"off",
            fullScreen:"on",

            spinner:"spinner0",

            stopLoop:"off",
            stopAfterLoops:-1,
            stopAtSlide:-1,

            shuffle:"off",


            forceFullWidth:"off",
            fullScreenAlignForce:"off",
            minFullScreenHeight:"400",

            hideThumbsOnMobile:"off",
            hideNavDelayOnMobile:1500,
            hideBulletsOnMobile:"off",
            hideArrowsOnMobile:"off",
            hideThumbsUnderResolution:0,

            hideSliderAtLimit:0,
            hideCaptionAtLimit:0,
            hideAllCaptionAtLilmit:0,
            startWithSlide:0,
            fullScreenOffset:"0px"
        });

        apiRevoSlider.bind("revolution.slide.onloaded",function (e) {
            setTimeout( function(){ SEMICOLON.slider.sliderParallaxDimensions(); }, 200 );
        });

        apiRevoSlider.bind("revolution.slide.onchange",function (e,data) {
            SEMICOLON.slider.revolutionSliderMenu();
        });

    }); //END REVOLUTION SLIDER

</script>
```

Comment: im not sure i understand the question.. are you trying to get the unselected images to load in the background while the current image is displayed?

Comment: @Ash The idea is that when you first open the website for example www.test.com the slider images loop should be 1,2,2a,2b,3.jpg. Now after the last image 3.jpg the next images should be 2a,2b,3,2a,2b,3.jpg. Images 1,2.jpg should be interrupted and continue loading the images 2a,2b,3.jpg....

Comment: Can you please provide a working fiddle?